# Docker (NGINX, PHP, mySQL) and Windows - File Permissions

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I've been looking into docker for a few hours; I'm running Windows 8.1 as the host machine, and VirtualBox with boot2docker.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports: 
        - "6603:3306"    
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
        MYSQL_USER: mysql
fpm:
    image: php:7.0.2-fpm
    volumes:
        - /c/Users/Administrator/www:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    links:
        - mysql
nginx:
    image: nginx 
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - /c/Users/Administrator/www:/var/www/html
    links:
        - fpm
```

This works fine (I can go to my docker ip address and see the nginx welcome page); although when I run mkdir for example (through php) it will give an error regarding windows permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `volumes` tag instead of `volumes_from`

- `volumes` can mount directories from host machine to container
  and
- `volumes_from` mounts directories from other services or containers

Please look at [docker-compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver)

And your docker-compose file should look like this:

```
fpm:
    image: php:7.0.2-fpm
    volumes:
        - /c/Users/Administrator/www:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    links:
        - mysql
nginx:
    image: nginx 
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes_from:
        - fpm
    links:
        - fpm
```

Comment: Spelling mistake; it's actually volumes in reality. - still doesn't fix the permission issue though.

Comment: No permission to create directory

Comment: I mean the docker runs up well, but if you try mkdir with php it wont work.

Comment: If anyone finds how to sort this out let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the way the Windows filesystem is shared with the VirtualBox Virtual Machine, using VirtualBox guest additions.

Files shared with the VirtualBox VM are owned by user "docker" and group "staff" inside the VM. Processes inside the VM (and containers) cannot change ownership of those files.

As a workaround, you can try to run your container as the same `uid`/`gid` of those files ([`--user 1000:50`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/));

```
-u, --user=""                 Username or UID (format: <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])
```

--ulimit=[]                   Ulimit options

There's also an open issue on the GitHub issue tracker that mentions some workarounds; [#581 Only root can write to OSX volumes / Can't change permissions within](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581)

Comment: Can we get reference to `--user` param usage? As far as I now docker will have user mapping from  v1.10

Comment: That's a different feature; user namespaces will allow you to remap the root user daemon-wide (not per container). The `--user` feature has been in Docker for quite a while. I'll add a link to the documentation

Comment: I cannot run docker-compose up --user; should I try something else?

Comment: It seems like there isn't any proper explanations for how to sort this out :s

Comment: You can add `user:` to the `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Same... Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4 

Tried with user: "1000:50" and "root" too.. same problem :)

Comment: Do you by any chance know how I can run a bash script from docker-compose for each container?